# RSpec td tag not returning data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, integration-testing

I'm using a table to represent a rota and I want to use RSpec to test that the date is appearing:

```
 describe "Checking the rota" do

    let(:service){ FactoryGirl.create(:service)}
    before{ visit root_path } #this is where the rota is displayed
    it{ should have_selector('td', date: service.date) }

  end
```

As far as I can tell the application itself is working fine as the rota is displaying perfectly when I visit the page myself. I'm curious as to why the test is failing though. The factory script I'm using is:

```
factory :service do
    date Date.today
    leader "Bob"
    singers "Mr T"
    soundAM "Thor"
    soundPM "Wobbles"
  end
```

Finally the stub I'm using to render the rota:

```
<% if(service.date < Date.today) %>
  <% service.destroy %>
<% end %>
<tr>
    <td><%=link_to service.date, edit_service_path(service.id) %></td>
    <td><%= service.leader %></td>

    ...</tr>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right line is:

```
it{ should have_selector('td', text: service.date) }
```

Depends if you're using Capybara or Webrat